# How to display all images within a folder with PHP

Tags: php, foreach, glob

I am currently using the following code to return a page that displays all the pictures within a folder:

```
echo'';   $array=glob('ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/*');
foreach($array as $zf) 
echo '<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/'.$zf.'">’;
```

I need to be be able to do similar to the below code, except there needs to be two occurrences of each picture in the code and I need to dynamically add the word "image1, image2, etc" for however many pictures there are in the folder. . . .   as shown below.   The below example shows just two pictures but I need it to return code for however many pictures are in the folder.

```
<div class="slider">

<input type="radio" name="slide" id="image1" checked/>
<label for="image1">
<img   src="http://www.gbamedical.com/ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/IMG_9633.JPG"/>
</label>
<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/IMG_9633.JPG" height="480"/>

<input type="radio" name="slide" id="image2"/>
<label for="image2">
<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/IMG_9638.JPG"/>
</label>
<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/IMG_9638.JPG" height="480"/>
</div>
```

Comment: just add an counter var to the loop?

Comment: Thanks Philipp!  Can you help a bit more?  I am so new to coding. . . .  I don't know what to do with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$array = glob('ebayimg/9150gba041117/size_2/*');
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $image) {
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="image<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
    <label for="image<?php echo $i ?>">
        <img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    </label>
    <img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Perfect   . . . Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because [glob()](http://php.net/glob) returns an numeric-based array, use the *$key* => *$value* syntax of [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). That way `$index` will correspond to the indexes (0 - the last index). Also, [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) can be included conditionally with a string. See the example below.

```
foreach($array as $index => $zf) 
    $checked = ''; //not checked
    if (!$index) { // equal to 0, for first item
        $checked = 'checked';
    }
    echo '<input type="radio" name="slide" id="image'.($index+1).'" '.$checked.'/>'.
         '<label for="image'.($index+1).'">'.
         '<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/'.$zf.'" />'.
         '</label>'.
         '<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/'.$zf.'" height="480" />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!